# how do I route/ping from home router's clients to another AP's(raspberryPI) client. here, AP and router client is in same network

Tags: networking, ping

I have 3 RPi (pi1, pi2 and pi3) and 2 (pi1 and pi2) of them are connected to home router and receive IP address dynamically.

One of the pi(pi2) is used as AP mode and another (pi3) pi is connected in this AP (pi2) as shown in picture. I can ping from pi3 to pi1 but cannot ping Pi1 to Pi3. As for the setting, I only configure AP mode in pi2. All the routes are default. what do I need to do to ping all of them

Doesn't matter which version of pi I just need basic ideas how to do this.

[image: Schematic of configuration]

Answer (score 1):

You can only ping (or anything else) between devices **on the same subnet**.

You would need to implement some form of routing between the subnets, but this is not straightforward, and without details of what you have done is unanswerable.

Comment: pi1 - just connected to home wi-fi and haven't done any thing. In pi2 I have configured to enable ipforward, NAT and in pi 3 all I have done is that it receive a static IP from pi 2. All pi have internet excess but cannot connect from pi1 to pi3

Comment: i want to send packets to dist. 172.24.0.0/16 subnet somehow, But my router doesn't know so it is possible to configure this without configuring my home router

Comment: Even if i have to do how can i configure so that the packet with dest. 172.24.0.0/16 endup in 192.168.2.227

Comment: Have you tried adding routing entry on Pi2? ```sudo route add default gw 172.24.1.75 ap0```

Comment: @Sergiusz I have tried that too but still cannot route :(

Comment: @Milliways sorry i'm new here where should I discuss this problem

Comment: @Sai9898 your comment has NOTHING to do with my answer, so I don't need to be notified. Post any comments under the Question (and feel free to delete your Comments here).